Android Google Maps Sdk is showing a blank gray screen
My android application has Google Maps Sdk version 18.2.0.
Everything was right until 14.5.24, when about 50% of devices running the app started to show blank gray screen with Google logo at the bottom.
I found out that when clearing Google Play Services cache, app is showing map ok, but after some minutes, if user does another things with his device, the problem is returning again. Probably, a piece of data saved on this cache, makes it all.
Anyway, asking user to clear this cache is too overkill, and this solution is not an option.
I found that on May 13, Google has released a new version here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).
I guess it has a significant connection.
The number of this version is 24.16.16.
I want to note that i did not see any interesting log from the device on the Logcat.
Some details:
compileSdkVersion 34
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 34
java version: 1.8
Maps sdk: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0
Play services Sdk: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1
Google Services plugin: com.google.gms.google-services
Gradle file: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
Here is my gradle file:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.0'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.6.10'
        classpath 'com.github.kezong:fat-aar:1.3.8'
    }
}


Does anyone encountered this problem? Does anyone has another solution?
What i've tried so far(with no success):

Downgrading Google Maps Sdk version.
Changing build gradle version and Google services version.
Using another Map api key.
Maps api is enabled, billing configuration is ok.


Solved!
The line: android:hardwareAccelerated="true", that appeared under "application" tag, appeared once again under "activity" tag, but now it was android:hardwareAccelerated="false", which means that the app is using extended memory, but in this specific activity -which is the map activity - not. Without this memory the map cannot be rendered properly (setting value for this attribute must be done carefully, because of its affect).


I think it is work for you try this...
